# C structure to Java object by pointer

Tags: java, native, jna

I have access to the address of a pointer to a C struct. It doesn't matters how I got it, I verified and it is received correctly.

The C definition looks like:

```
union Data_u
{
  long long u_integer;
  struct another_s u_another;
};
struct Data_s
{
  unsigned long s_Type;
  union Data_u s_Value;
};
```

I need to map the `Data_s*` to a similar structure in Java.
I searched over the internet and found the [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) library which I thought I can use.

I did not find a proper way to tranlsate the C struct in Java structure using JNA. I saw I can define a counterpart Java structure, however, the JNA is used in accessing native calls and not in direct structure translation although is supporting it.

To be specific, I found some methods, say for example:

`static Structure updateStructureByReference(Class type, Structure s, Pointer address)`

...Which would allow me - I think - to fill the Structure with the Pointer address I have. The method has the **package** access and from this on I shall modify it to **public** which means I will start **hacking** the library...

Is there a simpler way to solve the problem, perhaps in the JNA itself or perhaps in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JNA you can easily pass your struct by value to Java, update it and send it back (by value).

I'm, pretty sure that it is impossible to have Java object, which is mapped by pointer to a C struct, because java and C are using different memory models